# Changing name of data frames inR

Tags: r, frames

I have the following problem. I have a number of csv files data frames named a,b, c,...,m. I want to load them and change their names to a1,a2,a3, etc How can I do it in R?

I have tried the following, but it gives me an error:

```
  paste0("a",1)<-read.csv("a")
```

I also tried a way to rename the files after loading, but I don't know a way to it successfully.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to create multiple `data.frame` objects in the global environment (I would rather have those datasets within a list), you can read the specific files using `lapply` in a list, change the names of the list elements to the desired object names, finally use `list2env`.  For example, suppose I have 3 files `a.csv`, `b.csv`, and `c.csv` and want to create dataframe objects `a1`, `a2`, `a3` for those corresponding files.

```
 files <- list.files(pattern='^[a-z]\\.csv')
 nm1 <- paste0('a', 1:3)
 lst1 <- setNames(lapply(files, function(x) read.csv(x)), nm1) 
 list2env(lst1, envir=.GlobalEnv)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
assign(paste0("a",1),read.csv("a"))
```

If you don't want to have a line for each data set, you can list your `csv` files in a vector, named for example `list_files` and then do :

```
for (i in 1:length(list_files)){
     assign(paste0("a",i),read.csv(list_files[i]))
}
```